# Jenkins Multi-module build and checkstyle file that is created with external tool

Tags: javascript, jenkins, continuous-integration, checkstyle

we have a multi-module maven build setup for a JavaScript project. For static code analysis we have an external tool that is run via "Windows Batch" at the end of the whole build and lets the build fail if violations were found.

This works, but we cannot get the violations plugin report running. It always shows empty reports and no graphs. I assume it's a path issue.

The builds run in a master/slave config. So the absolute paths differ. I don't know, where (master or slave) the violations plugin actually performs its reports creation.

How does the violations plugin work, does it create the report for each submodule while the module is built? Than I guess it cannot work, to run the checks in the very end of the aggregation build.

Current setup:

```
Project root
|-src
|  |-sub-project1/pom.xml
|  |-sub-project2/pom.xml
|  `-pom.xml
`-checkresult.xml (with absolute file paths)
```

Would it be an option to integrate the checktool via exec-maven-plugin into the submodule poms?

Also currently our checkstyle report is not named checkstyle-result.xml, though, in the violations plugin a pattern can be specified. I don't know if that works.

Thanks!

Comment: For the path in the violations plugin..in Jenkins...do you have it set to **/checkresult.xml or if its on windows it might be **\checkresult.xml.